# Confusion when going from index notation to matrix notation

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, multiple-regression, matrix

In Andrew Ng's lectures on machine learning, on page 4 of his [first lecture notes](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf), he presents the cost function for the ordinary least squares regression model as:

$$
\begin{align}
J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{m} (\theta^T x^{(i)} - y^{i}))^2
\end{align}
$$

He then shows that the partial derivative can be shown as:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} J(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} (\theta^T x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) x_j^{(i)}
\end{align}
$$

However in the solution set he gives the gradient of $J(\theta)$ as:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_\theta J(\theta) = X^TX\theta - X^Ty
\end{align}
$$

My question is, how do I systematically go from the index form to the matrix form? As of right now, all I am doing is checking the dimensions of the matrices and making sure that they all come out correctly, but this seems to be inadequate. Yet I haven't found a good explanation as to how to convert from one form to the other. Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find it easier to go in the other direction: use the definitions of matrix multiplication and the gradient to convert the matrix formula into one involving the indexes.  This is purely mechanical (it's not hard to write a program to do it).  After a little practice you will find you can easily go in the other direction, too.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198257/intuition-for-the-product-of-vector-and-matrices-xtax/198280#198280

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All vector are columns vectors if not transposed. We have 
$$X = (x_1, \dots, x_p) = \begin{pmatrix}
(x^{(1)})^T \\
(x^{(2)})^T \\
\vdots \\
(x^{(n)})^T \\
\end{pmatrix}  \in \Re^{n \times p}$$. Now we can rewrite the sum as a dot product

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}J(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\theta^Tx^{(i)} - y^{(i)})x_j^{(i)} = w^Tx_j = x_j^Tw$$

For some vector $w$. Now

$$
w = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta^Tx^{(1)} - y^{(1)} \\
\theta^Tx^{(2)} - y^{(2)} \\
\vdots \\
\theta^Tx^{(n)} - y^{(n)} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta^Tx^{(1)}\\
\theta^Tx^{(2)}\\
\vdots \\
\theta^Tx^{(n)}\\
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
y^{(1)} \\
y^{(2)} \\
\vdots \\
y^{(n)} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
(x^{(1)})^T\theta\\
(x^{(2)})^T\theta\\
\vdots \\
(x^{(n)})^T\theta\\
\end{pmatrix}
-
Y
=
X\theta - Y
$$
So we have shown that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}J(\theta) = x_j^Tw = x_j^T(X\theta - Y)$$
So in the end
$$
\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^T(X\theta - Y) \\
x_2^T(X\theta - Y) \\
\vdots \\
x_p^T(X\theta - Y) \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
X^T(X\theta - Y) = X^TX\theta - X^TY
$$

Comment: I see that this is the case just out of familiarity with linear algebraic notation; however, I have to say that I wouldn't be able to follow your answer if I was trying to understand this for the first time. It's not that your answer is wrong, but it is cut and dry in its pure mathematical notation with no English cushioning explanations.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Yeah you're probably right. Feel free to add anything that will improve friendliness now that all the math is here already : )

Comment: This would be completely against etiquette. I would write my own answer, but I think your answer is all that is needed. My suggestion was to make it more accessible, but it's up to you.

Comment: @AntoniParellada, perhaps it might be against etiquette, but given that Lukasz doesn't mind, perhaps you could go ahead and make it more accessible, at least for me? =)

Comment: @oort It's not that I don't want to do it myself, if you can specify which step is not clear I will try to explain in more detail

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad first of all, thank you for the response. The second line where you talk about converting the sum to a dot product was helpful. However what is not clear to me is whether this is always the case. Would there be instances when you could not make the assumption that we are performing a dot product?

Comment: @oort Dot product of vectors $a,b$ is simply applying matrix multiplication (to  row vector and column vector), so we end with a scalar. $$a^Tb = \sum_i (a_i * b_i)$$ So in no way it is specific to the case above

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad this has been very helpful. Just to make sure I'm on the right track though, would it be correct to say that $\nabla_\theta J(\theta)$ can be written in index notation as: $\nabla_\theta J(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^m (\theta^T x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) x^{(i)}$ ?